# How to keep bars same size even when adding new datasets

Tags: chart.js

When I'm adding new datasets to a horizontal bar chart, they scale based on barPercentage.

I want to add new datasets and keep the size of the bars the same. I've tried using **barThickness** to always get the same size on the bars, but that just overlaps the bars because the category y-axis doesn't increase as well.

How can I set a specific **barThickness** while also scale the y-axis dynamically to fit the size of the bars?

As you can see in the example below, adding two datasets overlaps the bars. I want to be able to keep the size of the bars, and instead increase the Y-axis size to fit them both, and do so dynamically so that when adding/removing datasets, it will auto-resize.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        
var data = {
         labels: ['label1','label2','label3','label4'],
     
     datasets: [
    
    {
            label:'mydataset1',
        barThickness: 22,
        data: [1,2,3,4],
        backgroundColor:'red',
    },
    
    
    {
            label:'mydataset2',
        barThickness: 25,
        data: [1,2,3,4],
        backgroundColor:'blue',
    }
    
    
    ]
    
    
 
 }
 
 
var options = {

  responsive:true,
  maintainAspectRatio:true,
  
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
        
            ticks : {
                        
                max : 12,    
                min : 0,
                        }

        }],
        
        yAxde: [{
        
        
        }],
        
    }
};
      
      
       var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
       
            type: 'horizontalBar',

            data: data,
            
            options: options,
            
            });
```

```css
            .chartWrapper {
                position: relative;
            }

            .chartWrapper > canvas {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            .chartAreaWrapper {
                height: 85vh;
                background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
      <canvas id="myChart" height="100px"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a runnable code snippet that illustrates what you currently have?

Comment: here's a fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uxndt5Lj/),  if you remove the commented dataset, it will add the second dataset to the chart, and you will see that the two bars now overlap. What I want to do is keep the size of the bars, but increase the size of the label categories so they now fit both in same category. Since I will add more datasets to the charts eventually, it needs to automatically adjust the height when adding/removing datasets.

Answer (score 0):

use property  `barThickness: 'flex'` so that `chartjs` will automatically adjust the thickness whenever data is added or removed from the chart.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var data = {
  labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'],

  datasets: [

    {
      label: 'mydataset1',
      barThickness: 'flex',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },


    {
      label: 'mydataset2',
      barThickness: 'flex',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
    {
      label: 'mydataset3',
      barThickness: 'flex',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    }


  ]



}


var options = {

  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,

  scales: {
    xAxes: [{

      ticks: {

        max: 12,
        min: 0,
      }

    }],

    yAxde: [{


    }],

  }
};


var chart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'horizontalBar',

  data: data,

  options: options,

});
```

```css
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper>canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  height: 85vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
      <canvas id="myChart" height="100px"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I may have been at bit unclear. I actually don't want the bars to flex, I want all bars to have thickness 10 and the Y axis to scale accordingly whenever a new dataset is added.